# find whether my micro-controller is 8 bit or 16 bit using c program

Tags: c, architecture, bit

How to find the given controller is either of 8/16/32 bit machine.I have tried by assigning the values into char to find the bit position of value.

Comment: Are you trying to do that at runtime or at compile time ?

Comment: This is what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650004/how-can-find-using-c-program-whether-my-machine-is-16-bit-or-32-bit-or-64-bit

Comment: None of the answers there will work for a microcontroller.

Comment: @Wintermute Then you didn't read all the answers.

Comment: @ElderBug Which one do you have in mind? Those that don't require operating systems assume that the pointer size is the register size of the architecture, which is not true on, among others, 8-bit AVRs.

Comment: @Wintermute I was talking about `sizeof(int)`, and preprocessor methods.  I agree that `sizeof(int)` could be unreliable, but is usually right. Even `sizeof(char*)` will usually be right, as it is often different from `sizeof(const char*)`. Even 8-bit AVR use a 8-bit addressing with banks iirc. Anyway, a preprocessor switch should always be able to determine the word size.

Comment: @ElderBug `sizeof(int)` is 2 on 8-bit AVRs, as is `sizeof(char*)` (same with any other pointer). The C standard does not even allow `sizeof(int) == 1` on architectures where `CHAR_BIT == 8`, and most 8-bit AVRs could not address their internal SRAM with 8-bit pointers, so they use 16-bit pointers. I have never seen an AVR that used bank switching.

Comment: @Wintermute Right. Now that you mention it, `int` is supposed to be at least 16-bit (Though I'm 100% sure I have seen a compiler with `sizeof(int)==1`; probably not a good one). About the banks, I'm probably confusing with another MCU. Preprocessor should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell through C code.

First of all, note that 8 bit, 16 bit etc refers to the CPU *data bus*, which is not necessarily of the same width as the CPU *address bus*.

Although there are no guarantees about the default type sizes in the C standard, generally the size of `int` corresponds to the width of the data bus. Except this is not true for 8 bit processors.

Similarly, the size of a pointer corresponds to the size of the address bus, but the address bus is not necessarily of the same width as the data bus.

As a rule of thumb (no standard exists):

```
Data bus  Addr bus   int  long    pointer
   8        16       16   32      16
  16        16       16   32      16
  32        32       32   32      32
  64        64       32   32/64   64
```

Comment: @Lundlin, I don't think 'sizes' refer to the bus width because the bus can be multiplexed. I think they refer to the register width and the hardware architecture manages the multiplexing. Just remeber the old 8086 which had 8 but bus with but 16 bit registers and the CPU multiplexed the data over the bus. Similarly, the address bus can be multiplexed. That is just a matter of designng how many pins of the chip you use for what.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It's always been a bit fuzzy, but the sizes ultimately refer to the maximum chunk of data that the CPU can process with only one single instruction. Which is equal to the "theoretic" data bus, if you will.

Comment: that means that 'size' refers to register size, as that is what the CPU can process in a single instruction. Again, the hardware multiplexes over smaller buses, both address and data (and sometimes the clock speed is double for that). So the "theoretic data bus width" is just the register width, independent of multiplexing if less pins are available.